# Get post from custom post type that title is like custom string

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I need to get one post from custom post type named ( '`player`' ) that title = `"Player"`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more detail and your research also. A descriptive question will help you getting a pinpoint answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [get_page_by_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) function :

```
$post = get_page_by_title( 'Post Title', OBJECT, 'player' );
```

Comment: what is return, its not return images

Comment: You get the post object in return. See the link in my answer. Your question is not saying anything about images ? what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I have custom post type (player), and i have tag like ("player"), So in tags page i need to show only one post from custom post type (player) and show it in the top page of tag.
    
    How can do that ...

Comment: @KhalidAhmed Please file an edit to your question and add that info **inside** your question. The answerer answered what you asked. Please don't waste anyone's time with incorrect or incomplete info